# Glossy object is almost invisible when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I am designing a logo for a friend, but when I render the object doesn't show up.
At first I assumed that it was a problem with the background World color, since the object is glossy, I thought that all the faces were reflecting the same color evenly - but there aren't even any shadows...

[image]

So I tried adding a HDRi image, but the whole scene became beige instead of white.

I tried adding color objects to see if they were reflected by the glossy object, and they were, but everything seems to be absorbed by the World color.

[image]

Ideally, right now, I just want to see the object turn, I don't care about the background for the moment.

[image]

Comment: You have a perfectly glossy object but nothing to reflect on it. On a perfectly white environment your object reflects... white.

Comment: Look at a mirror. How do you light it? Do you light the mirror or the objects reflected on it?

Comment: This question it too vague.

Comment: I understand, but shouldn't there be areas with more and less lights? Like shadows for example? What about the light directed straight at the object, why isn't that reflected on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with glossy objects, like mirrors, you have to think that instead of lighting the object, you need to take care of whatever is being reflected on it.

So create something interesting that can be reflected on your mirror-like object and make it stand out from the backdrop:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Musgrave texture... I'll look into it. I think there's something about orthographic projections and shadows maybe that causes the problem I have...

Comment: @fabriced Shadows are very hard to see in glossy objects. Again, don't think in terms of lighting the object, but dealing with reflections. The object will catch those reflections.  Get the glossiest object you can find in your real world surroundings and study it to see what I mean. Also do a search for how to photograph shiny objects.

Comment: thanks! i understand the way reflecting objects work, I think it's more the way the world environment emits the same amount of light everywhere that I don't get. Also, there's an emission object (sphere visible on my second capture) that should make a difference, no? If the world is dark, the sphere should cast light on the logo, but it doesn't?...